# How long can Joe go without liquid water?

Tags: science-based, biology, humans

I am mad scientist and I captured Average Joe, who is not average only in one remark: He is person [not to be missed](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23146/how-many-humans-can-i-abduct-without-getting-noticed) (I double checked). Otherwise he is healthy male, around 30 years old, with no food allergies (I also checked)

I kidnapped this Joe and locked him inside controlled experiment: He is in "jail" which contains no running water in any kind.

I plan to provide him with any vegetables and fruit he wants. He is also getting other sources of food. But no running water.

Joe is going to be noticed, that if he survives for 60 days, I am going to release him with bag full of money (say 500 000 USD in various small amount banknotes)

Is he going to make it? What changes can I expect on his body?

Things to consider:

- Shower: No shower, he gets baby wipes.
- Toilet: Chemical toilet, I am going to change it regularly while he sleeps
- Day/Night: I am going to simulate usual day with changing the lighting dynamically, providing Joe at least 9 hours of "night"
- Humidity: Average air humidity
- Cooperation: Joe decided to cooperate and wants the money

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**SIGN ME UP**

You can get hydration from almost anything you can eat, even a nice piece of bread.  Foods like cucumbers, watermelons, and even strawberries will have [a lot of water](http://www.livestrong.com/article/350652-percentage-of-water-in-fruits-vegetables/) (90%-ish).  Cucumber and lettuce are among the highest.

A balanced diet high in vegetables and a few fruits will see him through 60 days just fine, all other things considered.  He should emphasize the vegetables (cucumbers, etc.) over the fruits (watermelons, etc.), because super high natural sugar from fruits can be a little detrimental although not noticeable in 60 days, but can also cause diarrhea at first.

Answer (score 8):

### 60 days? piece of cake, you said you'll provide him ANY vegetables and fruits!

Bet he'd ask for watermelons, melons ,cucumbers and other vegetables/ fruits with lots of water,so it's no problem.

However sitting in same place not moving doing nothing for 60 days is true torture, you must be mad to do it,and bet he'll scream, his family and friends will notice he's gone and will search for him, aint think you'll hold ihm for whooping 60 days like this.

Comment: Assumption given in my question: I checked that this person is not to be missed.

Comment: and he randomly wants some insane kidnappers cash? whoah ,he must be super dissapointed with life homeless emo suicidal Joe. Actually, even that kindo f person wouldn't believe you're giving him 500,000USD $ just for sitting there and having unlimited supply of food and 24/7 baby-like care (maybe order him some prostitutes too? xD)

Comment: all the people in reality shows like "The Big Brother"? ;)

Answer (score 3):

**In terms of water, he'll be just fine.** As everybody else has noted, fruits and vegetables have a lot of water in them. Since he can have any fruit or vegetable he wants, he's gonna be pretty happy in this regard.

I'm more concerned with the remains of his food. After all, it's not like he's going to eat watermelon rinds, apple cores, or even carrot tops. He'll probably leave those in a corner. Assuming you're not going to clean those up at night, they'll most likely rot after 60 days. Even worse, he'll be stuck in a room full of rotting leftovers.

As for changes on his body, expect him to gain weight. He *is* in an almost empty room with nothing to do but eat. Heck, he's probably going to crack from boredom if you don't give him any form of entertainment for 60 days.

Comment: Just toss it in the chemical toilet OP said to be emptied nightly (or it's a big enough chute down there)

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to drink the whole "8 glasses of water" (or whatever it currently is).  You can get your water from moist foods, which vegetables and fruits will be great at providing.

It is quite likely that he will feel thirst and crave a drink, but he will survive.

Comment: Especially if it's not too hot in the cell (OP already said it's alright humidity wise) and the guy doesn't exercise much, the required amount of water drops massively

Answer (score 2):

## Fruits and Vegetables in 60 days.

The first thing that came to mind when you mentioned any food was coconuts. They aren't ideal for sports, but if Joe is in a room not doing much of anything, he would be fine. Not to mention that he could eat cucumbers and other foodstuffs with high water content. I believe that you be coming out of this situation a few bucks short.

Answer (score 1):

Are you preventing him from juicing?  Just juice everything by hand and drink the liquids. :)

Yeah, he can totally make it.

He might want to drink his urine too.  You can cycle that back through a couple times, it just works your liver a lot harder.